# stability using linearization instead of Lyapunov fails

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Consider the following system of equations

$$\begin{cases}
x'=-y-x^3 \\ 
y'=x-y^3 \\ 
\end{cases}
$$
Then, its only equilibrium is $(x^*,y^*)=(0,0)$. Using the Lyapunov function

$$V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$$

one can prove that the equilibrium $(x^*,y^*)=(0,0)$ is asymptotically stable.

I also tried to use linearization, which gives the system
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x' \\
    y' \\
    \end{pmatrix}
=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
The matrix has two eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm i$ and their real part is zero. So, as I understand, we can't infer anything about stability of $(0,0)$ from the linearization of the system?

Comment: Yes that is true. When the real parts is zero one cannot deduce stability from linear dynamics alone.